# use of CRM bitrix24 form embed code in php page

Tags: winforms, crm

Help Me to use CRM Bitrix 24 embed code. I want to use this code in my PHP web page. How can I use it. Actually  I want to popup this form when I click on a button in my PHP page. anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow,
here's how you can insert your Bitrix Form Embed code inside a PHP code:
you can easily insert the code this way:

```
<?php
  /* your PHP code here*/
  ?> COPY & PAST YOUR BITRIX FORM EMBED CODE <?php
?>
```

You can easily insert any HTML code into a PHP code by closing the PHP script tag "**?>**" insert your HTML code, then open the PHP tag again "**<?php**" so that the rest of you PHP code will run correctly.

There are other ways to do this but this should be the easiest way.